# How to rotate app with TabBar?

Tags: xcode, ipad, tabbar

Hi I have a splitview app that is working fine until I add a TabBar in the rootview section. The problem is that when I add the TabBar to the rootview the app does not rotate to landscape, if I change the orientation the view remains in portrait mode.
How can I solve this?. Hope you can help

```
#import "SplitViewTest3AppDelegate.h"
#import "SISACWelcomeViewController.h"

@implementation SplitViewTest3AppDelegate

@synthesize window, masterViewController, splitViewController,masterViewTabBarController, searchViewController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    masterNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Folder.png"];

    //NewsFeedsNavigationController *newsFeedsNavigationController = [[NewsFeedsNavigationController alloc] init];
    SISACWelcomeViewController *sisacWelcomeViewController = [[SISACWelcomeViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sisacWelcomeViewController];

    searchViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil];
    searchViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search-icon.png"];

    masterViewTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    masterViewTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, searchViewController, nil];

    masterViewController.detailNavigationController = detailNavigationController;

    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterViewTabBarController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    splitViewController.delegate = sisacWelcomeViewController;

    // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    //[masterNavigationController.view addSubview:tab.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     */
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    //[tab release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
I had the same issue.
Without the TabBar all is well, add the TabBar and the rotation breaks.
I guessed that there is something broken in the responder chain or view hierarchy.
So I was about to submit as a bug. So wrote a test app to demo to Apple (because they ALWAYS ask for one), and it worked. Hooray, but why?

These are my findings from the Apple docs.
From the View Programming Guide for iOS.
Split View Controller
"A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create." 
Thus they should not be embedded within a TabBar View, although I understand that there is a workaround out in the wild.

Also:
Creating a Tab Bar Interface
"Install it as one of the two root views in a split view interface. (iPad only)"

Solution:
After much more investigation, and some trial and error, I found the issue.
Of course it seems so obvious NOW.
When the SplitView tests for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, it tests every possible view on the whole hierarchy, that is EVERY view in the MasterView, thus EVERY view in the TabBar, and EVERY view in the DetailView, thus EVERY view in the current NavigationStack.
The fly in the ointment is that a newly created ViewController does not support Landscape by default.

Where I had gone wrong was: I had created ALL of the TabBar subviews, but not written any more code yet, because I wanted to get the SplitView with TabBar working first, thus 1 of my Tab Views had not been changed from the default.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is correct.  If you are adding tabs which include using the CoreDataTableView controller (that is used with the CS193P course), be sure to add a method to allow for any orientation.  If not, your split view will not work correctly.