# UISplitViewController - willShowViewController Not Firing

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabcontroller

I am converting an iPhone application to work on the iPad.  In this case, the user interface was created with interface builder.  The interface of the root controller (at index 0), consists of a Tab Controller & Navigation Controllers in this layout:

- Tab Controller
- Navigation Controller 1
- Navigation Controller 2
- Navigation Controller 3

I have been implementing this in pieces.  When I setup the Tab Controller & Navigation Controller 1 as a first step, everything works correctly.  willHideViewController & willShowViewController work correctly.  My interface switches from SplitView to Popover correctly.  When I add Navigation Controller 2, willHideViewController & willShowViewController never fire & I always see the Popover controller no matter what orientation the iPad is within the simulator.

When I add a second navigation controller, is there something else I need to tie off within the interface builder to get the interface to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've set a delegate for the first navigation controller but not one for the second. The delegate object would receive methods like willHideViewController.

I'm also not sure that having multiple navigation controllers is good style. A view controller knows that it has been placed in a navigation controller, and you can access this with self.navigationController. You should keep pushing view controllers on the same navigation controller. Or I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do with your tab controller.

Comment: I used the splitView template generated by Xcode 4 as the basis for adding iPad support to my project.  In this splitView template, the delegate that handles willShowViewController/willHideViewController is the DetailViewController.  I believe this delegate is implemented correctly, since everything works when the RootController is nothing more than a tabController with a single tab implemented.  When I add a second tab to the RootController is when things stop working.  When I remove the additional tab, everything starts working again.

Comment: BTW, there are 3 navigation controllers, one per tab in the tab bar.  When a tab is selected, the navigation controller for that tab ends up pushing view controllers to eventually select an item.  So, I'm pretty sure I'm using the controllers correctly.  This implementation works correctly as an iPhone app.  I only see issues when I try to make the iPhone interface work correctly for a splitView.

Comment: One additional bit of information:  The tabs that cause problems with the (root) splitView are the ones that implement a core data table with the CortDataTableViewController class that's available from the Stanford course materials.  When this class is added to the nib, things fail.  Remove it & things work normally.

Comment: The template creates RootViewController.m, which inherits from UITableViewController. How did you turn it into a UITabBarController? You could have changed the header file to@interface RootViewController : UITabBarController

Comment: Read this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023695/how-to-rotate-app-with-tabbar -- This is the fix in this case.  In my case I didn't implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation methods within my core data table objects.  With the iPhone version, I was more concerned with learning core data than implementing orientation methods.  THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is pretty simple:  When you implement the split view controller & you want everything to switch correctly from portrait to landscape, you need to make sure that all the interface elements implement *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation* for portrait & landscape layouts.